# how to vertically center element in this case (prefer no javascript)

Tags: html, css

Two components: parent(white box) and child(grey box). And I want to place child in the center of parent vertically.

Three constrains are:

1. parent has fixed height, overflow-y is auto.
2. child has variable height, and the height may be less than or greater than  parent's height.
3. child is a normal component(div), not just an image or a paragraph of text.

Since child has variable height, I choose to use "absolute position + translate" to achieve this, like:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

It works well when child's height is less than parent's.

If child's height is greater than parent's, bad things happened(see picture (b) below). The problem is that I can't scroll to the top of the child. I guess it's the "translate-y" that cause child gets cropped.

The live demo is on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p50y4dLn/5/)

How can I overcome this issue? Is there any better way to do this?

[click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvPTr.png)

Comment: I found a method and answer the question below, you can see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I find the answer..

Use ":after inline-block" trick

```
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: white;
}

.parent:after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

Live demo: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q8b9owr2/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You may give the child a specific `height` and also use `overflow: auto;`. This will center your child into your parent container and also the text should only be seen in the child itself.

[See here](https://jsfiddle.net/p50y4dLn/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you use position absolute, it needs to be position relative + adjust the margins left and right.

```
.child {
 position:relative;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 width: 200px;
 height: auto;
 background-color: grey;
}
```

Here is a working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p50y4dLn/1/)

You can still add `top: 50%;` etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, but I think you've misunderstood my question. I want the child can be centered vertically **when it's height is less than parent's**. Anyway, thanks for your help ; )

Comment: Okay but it will be always centered, even if the height is less or more then the parents height, you could add overflow:auto to the child for the scroll function. Try changing the height, it works in all cases?

Answer (score 0):

You want this :)

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: white;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  top: 0%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: grey;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Et quinta decima eodem modo typi qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari fiant sollemnes in. Id quod mazim, placerat facer possim assum typi non habent claritatem insitam est usus. Dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod
    tincidunt ut laoreet? Gothica quam nunc putamus parum claram anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima. Duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend. Nulla facilisis at, vero eros et accumsan
    et iusto odio dignissim. Demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius claritas est. Iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat vel illum dolore eu feugiat? Vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate
    velit esse molestie. Ex ea commodo consequat duis autem consequat vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla. Augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi nam liber tempor. Lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius claritas. Litterarum formas humanitatis
    per seacula quarta, decima et quinta decima. Eorum claritatem Investigationes demonstraverunt est etiam processus dynamicus qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum mirum est! Minim veniam quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis
    nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I think you've misunderstood my question. I want the child can be centered vertically **when it's height is less than parent's**. Anyway, thanks for your help ; )

Answer (score -3):

you need to set a line-height on the child.

```
.child { line-height:  400px; }
```